# Mirror to the past

Tags: physics

Are there any holes in the following reasoning?

Black holes form gravitational lenses. So they bend light.
Is it possible for an observer to see his own past image as a result of light bending around a few black holes?

Answer (score 6):

### No

A [gravitational lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) has different optical properties to an 'ordinary' lens.  Whereas an ordinary lens 'bends light' more at the edges of the lens, a gravitational lens has greater deflection of light that passes close to the massive object.  So while there will be a precise radius at which incident light is deflected all the way around the black hole and back towards the observer, this cannot be used to form an image.  If you were to shine a very bright light towards the black hole (and then wait a very long time), you would eventually see a thin ring of light reflected back at you, but not a complete image.

Answer (score 1):

## No, but for a different reason

Stephen's [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/159308/36850) is valid; the light coming back towards the observer would be distorted, but assuming properties of the black hole were known, it could potentially be processed into something resembling the original image, if it weren't for two facts:

1. Light leaving an object is not [collimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimated_beam).  Minimum safe distance to a black hole means that vanishingly few photons that reflected off an observer would even reach it, because...
2. The interstellar medium is [dusty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_dust).  Even perfectly collimated light can only travel so far before it's scattered, absorbed, or otherwise dispersed.  So the information your observer would be after (the light that reflected from them) couldn't possibly make the round trip from them, to the black hole, and back.

Comment: To give an idea of the scale of the problem, Pluto is between 4 and 7 light-hours from Earth (depending on its orbit). When the Hubble looks at Pluto, it captures an image that is 4-7 hours "in the past". It also captures an image that looks something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pluto_moon_P5_discovery_with_moons%27_orbits.jpg). The further back you look, the harder it will be to resolve details.